# Get file height width before uploading using Javascript / Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am have Asp:FileUpload control on my webform.

On the **OnChange()** event of **FileUpload** control, JavaScript function is executed

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fUpload" runat="server" Style="visibility: hidden;width:1px" onchange="callme(this)"/>
```

**Javascript Function :**

```
function callme(oFile) {
    document.getElementById('<%=txtFilePath.ClientID%>').value = oFile.value;
    ReadImage(oFile.value);
}
```

ReadImage function should read the file and tell height width and size of the selected file and show error message if the file is not a Image.

```
function ReadImage(_file) 
{
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image = new Image();


    image.src = 'file://' + _file;              
    image.onload = function() {

            alert('Step 2');

            var w = this.width,
                h = this.height,
                t = file.type,                           
                n = file.name,
                s = ~ ~(_file.size / 1024) + 'KB';


            alert('<img src="' + this.src + '"> ' + w + 'x' + h + ' ' + s + ' ' + t + ' ' + n + '<br>');
        };
        image.onerror= function() 
        {
            alert('Invalid file type: '+ _file.type);
        };

    }
```

The ReadImage() function should read the file selected and get the Height, Width and Size of that file before uploading to the server.

***How this can be done?? What I am doing wrong.***

Comment: What is the value of `_file`?

Comment: any local file path on the user machine... ex: "C:\Users\amit_shelke\Pictures\as.jpg"

Comment: Are you sure it is not `C:/fakepath/as.jpg`?

Comment: Yes. If you try to run my code oFile.value = "C:\Users\amit_shelke\Pictures\as.jpg".

Comment: Okay, have you tried to set `onload` before `src` and do you get any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Yes checked with that too. No use. Alert message is place to check if the code is getting called.  Actually my problem is simple to explain, "I want to verify/validate correct image is getting uploaded. So I want to validate on client side before uploading."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function callme(oFile) 
{
    document.getElementById('<%=txtFilePath.ClientID%>').value = oFile.value;
    ReadImage(oFile);
}

function ReadImage(_file) {
    var fr = new FileReader;

    fr.onload = function () { // file is loaded
        var img = new Image;

        img.onload = function () {

            alert('Step 2');

            var w = img.width;
            var h = img.height;

            alert('<img src="' + fr.result + '"> ' + w + 'x' + h + '<br>'); // is the data URL because called with readAsDataURL
        };
        img.onerror = function () {
            alert('Invalid file type');
        };

       img.src = fr.result; // is the data URL because called with readAsDataURL

    };

    fr.readAsDataURL(_file.files[0]); // for using a <input type="file">
}
```

Comment: Your solution didn't work. Thanks for the try. img.onload() didn't trigger.

Comment: oh i just forget to put img.src, try now i have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

The remaining part of my question - "Get File size before uploading"

**Use this javascript**

```
 function checkFile(fieldObj) {
    var FileName = fieldObj.value;
    var FileExt = FileName.substr(FileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    var FileSize = fieldObj.files[0].size;
    var FileSizeMB = (FileSize / 10485760).toFixed(2);


    if ((FileExt != "png" && FileExt != "doc" && FileExt != "bmp" && FileExt != "dib" && FileExt != "JPG" && FileExt != "jpeg" && FileExt != "jpe" && FileExt != "jfif" && FileExt != "gif" && FileExt != "tiff" && FileExt != "tif" && FileExt != "tga") || FileSize > 10485760) {
        var error = "File type : " + FileExt + "\n\n";
        error += "Size: " + FileSizeMB + " MB \n\n";
        error += "Please make sure your file is in pdf or doc format and less than 10 MB.\n\n";
        alert(error);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

did you try without image.src = 'file://' + _file;

```
var img = new Image;

img.onload = function() {
    alert(img.width);
    alert(img.height);
};
img.onerror = function() {
    alert("error");
};
img.src = oFile.value;
```

Comment: Yes, already tried with what you suggested, but not working. Actually Alert(img.width) should give me exact value, but it is not. The reason might be I may require to create the object of Filereader class and pass it to Image class then your code can work, but I am new to javascript so couldn't find what exact code do I need to write.

Comment: i have posted another answer, i have made change in both callme and ReadImage function, it should work now.